# Create a 3d viewer on react or angular

Tags: reactjs, angular, web

For a project on a web application I need to show my product in 3D.

I have the 3D object with all component (es. a table composed by 4 legs and 1 top).

My goal is show my object assemled, on click expled the sub assembly and put on left a side bar with list off itmes. When I move mouse on a part on left illuminet the component and if component is out of stock color my component red if not color in green.

I see the https://modelviewer.dev/ but I don't find anything about explode or put a left side bar